# Php Login Page not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have following php script for login page. Problem is, whenever I submit my password, the page says, "Password doesn't match". I've checked the password stored in database, It matches with the one I'm  putting in password field. Can anyone correct me where I'm making a mistake?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username= htmlentities($_POST['username']);
    $password1= htmlentities($_POST['password']);
    $password= md5($password1);
    $query= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrow == 0){
        $error = 'Please enter correct username';
    }
    else if($numrow == 1){
        $run = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $dbid =$run['id'];
        $dbname =$run['name'];
        $dbusername =$run['username'];
        $dbpassword =$run['password'];
        $dbemail =$run['email'];
        $dbcourse =$run['course'];
        if($password == $dbpassword){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $dbid;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $dbname;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $dbpassword;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $dbemail;
            $_SESSION['course'] = $dbcourse;    
            header('Location:admin.php?add='.$dbid);
        } else {
            $error = 'password does not match';
        }               
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the password stored in the database also hashed with md5?

Comment: Do you use `htmlentities` when you insert? You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: as a side note if this is a public server PLEASE do not use MD5 as a hash algorithm. Use something stronger.

Comment: Do not `md5()` your passwords, it's not a proper way of hashing.  Here is a [**decrypter**](http://md5.gromweb.com/), to make my point.

Comment: print the values to the error log and see what's coming out!

Comment: _"I've checked the password stored in database, It matches with the one I'm putting in password field."_  This makes me suspect the password is stored in plaintext in DB, while this code tests password with MD5

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. It was because of hashed password, By removing md5, it works fine. Is it ok to use password without hashing?

Comment: @Nytrix -> while I don't at all dispute your recommendation to use something other than md5, its not really true that the decrypter you reference is a decrypter.. Its actually just a database of common hashes. If you try "decrypting" the md5 for 'john', that will work, its common enough, but try decrypting the md5 for something like 'johnisthebestever' and its not found, so this site could easily do the same lookup for other types of algorithms too. The reason I mention this is because it does also highlight the point that using a weak password is useless, regardless of the hashing function

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed -> no, you should insert your passwords with a hash, eg, `INSERT INTO admin values ('myusername', sha1('mypassword'));

Comment: @JohnMcMurray Yes, good point. It goes past my point that decrypting is fairly easy, I wanted to link an article about how to do it, I didn't find it as fast though. Why are you using `sha1()`? We have functions for that, why try to do it different.

Comment: @ JohnMcMurray thanks. I'll try your suggestion. Will notify you in case of any further problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the password you are entering matches the one stored in the database then this won't work because you are hashing the entered password with the `md5()` function.

Say the password is "password", in this code comparing the stored value "password" to the md5 hash which translates to "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99" is like using the following `if` condition:

```
"password" == "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"
```

Which evaluates to false.

Now, it would work if you removed the line hashing the password that was entered and just compared the plain text values, but that would be ridiculous. What you need to do is replace the password stored in the database with the hashed value of itself, and use a stronger hash function such as `sha1()`.

To quickly get the hash value of a string, go to http://www.sha1-online.com. Update the user record to the `sha1` hash and replace the use of `md5()` with `sha1()`

Comment: Thanks. But how to store a hashed password in database? As in my case, I'm registering the users directly from phpMyAdmin, not by INSERT query.

Comment: Instead of typing in the password to add for the user, get the hashed value by typing it into www.sha1-online.com and use the hash instead of the password. You should also look into salting the passwords (adding a random string to the end of the plain text password before you hash it) otherwise the hashed value can easily be looked up to the plain text password. If this is a public facing website you should definitely not go live until you've achieved such a basic level of security. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm